# Display array data in a table using ajax, jquery and symfony2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I would like to display data using jquery and ajax in a table in my twig file.

The ajax request sent a post request to the controller, the controller tried to insert severl row from a csv file in the database, but some error data cannot be inserted and I would like to display these data to the client using ajax and jQuery.

The data should be displayed in a table in my twig file. Until now, I can return the data, but I can't display the data in a table.

**This is my ajax code:**

```
jQuery('#formulaire').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function (arr, $form, options) {
        var ids = [];
        var values=[];
        $('li.ui-selected').each(function(){
            ids.push(this.id);
            values.push(this.value);
        });

        arr.push({name:'hide', value:(ids)})
        arr.push({name:'valueschamps', value:(values)});
    },
    success: function (result, request) {
        var parsedData =JSON.parse(result);
        jQuery('#data').append(parsedData.data);
        //jQuery('#data').html(parsedData.data);

    },
    error: function () {
        jQuery('#main-content').html("errors");
    }
});
```

In my controller I have:

```
$response = new JsonResponse();
$dataToReturn = array('data' => $dataerror);
$response->setData($dataToReturn);
return $response;
```

The result returned is as follows:

[image]

I want to display the data returned by the controller in a table inside the twig file. I tested several solutions, but does not work.

Any Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to loop over the json elements and create the table, for example:

```
function createTable(data) {
        var rowData;
        var rowHTML;
        var tableHTML = "<table>";

        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            rowData = data[i];
            rowHTML = "<tr>";

            for (var k = rowData.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
                rowHTML += "<td>" + rowData[k] + "</td>";
            }

            rowHTML += "</tr>";
            tableHTML += rowHTML;
        }

        tableHTML += "</table>";

        return tableHTML;
    }
```

And call it in the success callback like this:

> jQuery('#data').html(createTable(parsedData.data));

Comment: thank you very much for this response, It work perfectly. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the backend returns plain JSON.

so `jQuery('#data').append(parsedData.data);` will never work, since it is a javascript object.

You either have to create the elements via javascript as was previously suggested, or you have to return html with symfony. You can create a separate view for it if you like.

And then append the returned html like so:

`jQuery('#data').append(result);`